# best way to add multiple columns in power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Hi need to add 1000+ calculated columns in power bi which provide the count per entry, for example.*means calculated columns

| ID | RankCode | Count_RankCode* | RankAdvance | Count_RanAdvance* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | AAA | 2 | XYZ | 2 |
| 1001 | AAA | 2 | XYA | 1 |
| 1002 | AAB | 1 | XYZ | 2 |

found the right way to count in power BI DAX:

```
COUNTROWS(FILTER('24Jun_1973',[rankCode]=earlier([rankCode])))
```

Requirement:

- add 1000 columns that count rows in probably in one code using DAX
- or create the 1000 count cloumn in power query M language (need it to be fast since raw date is 60gb).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @smpa01, I was able to complete this task using the tabular editor.  Just used the DAX script in tabular editor, put my all my measures in there since I was able to create all expressio in excels as it is just repeating then voila, 1000 measures added.

example:

```
Measure '24Jun_1973'[measure]=calculate(COUNTROWS(FILTER('28Jun_1973',[rankcode]='28Jun_1973'[rankcode])))
Measure '24Jun_1973'[measure2]=calculate(COUNTROWS(FILTER('28Jun_1973',[rankAdvance]='28Jun_1973'[rankAdvance])))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you would want another 1000 columns.

If you really want to though, in powerquery, you could unpivot, group and count, append the results to original data, then re-pivot.  I don't know how fast it would be. I suspect not very.

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"RankCode", type text}, {"RankAdvance", type text}}),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

// group and count
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Attribute", "Value"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), type number}}),
#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Attribute", "Attribute - Copy"),
#"Change column name" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Duplicated Column",{{"Attribute - Copy", each "count_" & _, type text}}),

// append back to original table, then repivot

#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute", "Value"},#"Change column name",{"Attribute", "Value"},"Table2",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"Count", "Attribute - Copy"}, {"Count", "Attribute - Copy"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Table1",{"Attribute", "Value"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Count", "Value"}, {"Attribute - Copy", "Attribute"}}),
combined = #"Unpivoted Other Columns" & #"Renamed Columns",
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(combined, List.Distinct(combined[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value")
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @horseyride,

tried it now and it still calculating. will update accordingly.

Comment: try without the #"Pivoted Column"  step or with full code on smaller sample data set to see if working

Comment: it's working on small sample, like the one I sent.
However, for actual data, even for a one column (I deleted rest of column except randCode and ID) it takes about an hour to complete.
It's quite fast up to #"combined" step.  any suggestion?

Comment: With PowerQuery it would be painfully slow given the size of the data (60gig!). DAX would be much faster. Also, don't create calculated column in DAX which again will be extremely slow. Create only measures. I think using Tabular Editor you can create 1000 measures much faster than you can do in Power BI. However, given the size of the data, it is probably better to use SQL or databricks if you really want a performant query.

Comment: Hi @smpa01, based on 10-12 sec every measure/column, it would take me about 3+hours.  If that is a correct calculation, I am ok with it.

would appreciate though if you know any scripts to use in tabular editor that is applicable to my problem. Thanks.

Comment: As suggested by @smpa01, I was able to complet this task using the tabular editor.  Just used the DAX script, put my all my measures in there since I was able to create in excels since it is just repeating then voila, 1000 measures added.


'code' Measure '24Jun_1973'[measure]=calculate(COUNTROWS(FILTER('28Jun_1973',[rankcode]='28Jun_1973'[rankcode])))